# Programmatically Disable Button

Tags: jquery

I have a submit button that uses jQuery to post and then post back if there is any error, however if I add `attr('disabled','disabled');` to avoid the user clicking more than twice(post twice) somehow disabling the button does not work.

Please see the [fiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/zMKg5/).

Comment: It works, but your code is pretty poor. I simplified your example at  http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/zMKg5/2/. Your code for disabling the button doesn't even get setup until the button is clicked the first time, but you can see that on click #2 it works. That, and you should use `.prop()` over `.attr()`.

Comment: thx a lot! it works now, but one question, I have post error back if php find any error, but the button already disable, any way to solve this?

Comment: Not without seeing your other code.

Answer (score 2):

Use `.prop()`

```
.prop("disabled", true);
```

Also, enable jQuery on the left side of the fiddle.

Update: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/zMKg5/1/

Comment: But be aware that disabling a submit button can stop the form from being submitted

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `.attr('disabled', 'disabled')`, they do (almost) the same thing in this case (the difference is trivial). The primary problem was the lack of event handler definition on `document.ready`.

Comment: i tried, its not working, if i click very fast(many times), it still create 2 post inside of my DB

Comment: @user2178521 Perhaps you should set up a small time limit in your PHP file to prevent two posts from happening in rapid succession. Solve the problem with PHP instead of (or in addition to) with Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, lots of problems.

- You didn't load jQuery into your fiddle.
- You need to define event handlers before you use them, preferrably right after the page is ready with `$(function() { ... });`.
- You can just use `.click()` because you're disabling the button right away, which makes the code easier to read.

Fork with working code: http://jsfiddle.net/TLEG4/

Comment: sry i didn't copy all code, i just try to keep it simple, i do have ready function

Comment: @user2178521 You still need to define your event before you use it.